# How to extract the Email address of a downloaded File

Tags: email, email-attachments, mail-sender

I am trying to find a plugin or a browser attachment which would allow me to find out the email address of a file which has been downloaded!!! I have searched the web vigorously yet there hasn't been any luck!

To expand on my thought i would like the downloaded file name and email address of the sender to be stored in a file so that i can extract this information later.

The language isnt important and if there is an independent application which can monitor the download folder and extract the sender email address of a particular file that would be equally helpful.

Comment: What is the email address of a file?

Comment: A particular file which was originally an attachment and has been downloaded. The sender of the mail having this file as an attachment

Answer (score 0):

hum, looks like you are using Bing :) 
Let me give you this one

http://www.firatatagun.com/java-email-extractor-extract-email-address-from-string-text-file/2009/12/28/

... first google result :)

Comment: What i am trying to do is something like this!!! Suppose for example i downloaded a particular vikram.doc which was an attachment which came from kevin_45@gmail.com i want this "vikram.doc kevin_45@gmail.com" to be stored in a file!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using microsoft outlook then you can try [outlook email extractor](http://www.reverseapps.com/outlook-email-extractor/). Which will solve your problem.